# Will Loading Up My PCI Express Slots Affect GPU Performance?

Tags: graphics-card, pci-express

I wanted to know if loading up my PCI bus with different cards will affect my GPU's gaming performance.

I have a ASUS Maximus VI Formula with 3 PCIe x16 3.0 slots and 3 PCIe x1 slots. I have a single GPU in the first x16 slot (GTX 780ti), and a sound card in the first x1 (Creative XFi Titanium). I know the x16 slots can run in 3 modes: x16, x8 x8, and x8 x4 x4.

My question is if I add more cards in the x1 slots, or possibly non-graphics cards in the x16 slots, will it make my GPU run in x8 mode? Will that affect gaming performance? How much?

Comment: No; They are separate lanes for a reason.

Comment: I'd say the only time it might: When using dual PCIe x16 slots and the motherboard downgrades the GPU to x8.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the other "x16" slots (quotes because they have the x16 physical connector but not the wiring), 8 PCIe lanes will be stolen from the GPU connection to provide a link to the other two slots.

You won't notice a performance drop in games running at PCIe 3.0 x8 (which the 780Ti supports), and probably wouldn't even notice any slowdown in PCIe 2.0 mode on x8.